# How do I give elevated privileges to Docker in DevOps pipeline?

Tags: docker, azure-devops

I'm getting this error in my Azure Pipeline (devOps) when it tries to build the image and I can not find a solution for this problem. It only happens in few pipelines, and all of them are configured in the same way.

Here I leave an image with the error:

[image: Error description]

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The docker client must be run elevated to connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57460393/the-docker-client-must-be-run-elevated-to-connect)

Comment: It does not. My docker problem is building images in Azure DevOps not locally. And it only happens for few of them. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Please post formatted text, rather than pictures of text.

Comment: Do you mind check the 'Enable system diagnostics' when you run the build and share us the full debug logs?

Answer (score 0):

> Given that you provided few information i will make some assumptions
> and try to answer you question. Stuff you can try:

It is possible you have docker configured to run on linux container and you have a container that wants to run on top of a windows OS. So make sure you have all your containers on top of the same OS.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the user for your agent host:
["We changed the agent to run as the "devops" user and now it works.](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/2082)"

Side-note: Containers with a `ENTRYPOINT` *might not work*, since Azure Pipelines will `docker create` an awaiting container and `docker exec` a series of commands which expect the container is always up and running.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved. We had a custom agent, so we have a VM with Docker running inside it, and the solution was to run Docker with admin privileges