# How come "docker ps" has a different behaviour in PowerShell versus inside VS Code?

Tags: windows, docker, powershell, visual-studio-code

If I open a PowerShell, and type `docker ps`, this is what happens:

```
PS C:\Users\myself\dev> docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE        COMMAND                CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                       NAMES
5372832c4500   demo_flask   "python ./server.py"   8 minutes ago   Up 8 minutes   0.0.0.0:1234->1234/tcp, :::1234->1234/tcp   intel_chatelet
```

Whereas if I open a new terminal inside VS Code and do the same, this error happens:

```
PS C:\Users\myself\dev> docker ps
error during connect: This error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running.: 
Get "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/containers/json": 
open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

This is weird since these two shells are PowerShells.

How can I succesfully run "docker ps" in a VS Code terminal?

PS: I read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40459280/docker-cannot-start-on-windows) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57460393/the-docker-client-must-be-run-elevated-to-connect) but they do not solve the problem I'm facing. One shell can run docker while another cannot.